# VBA in find function runtime error 91

Tags: excel, vba, find, runtime

My question is concerning the runtime error 91 in VBA for excel. I've done some searching to no avail. My code is below. I have noted the section causing the error. Why is this happening, and how can i fix it and move on?

```
Sub RemoveFooterRows(theFile)
    Dim found As Range
    Dim aggregateRow

    ''Error is from section below
    found = isItRow = Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find _
        ("Summary", Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
    ''Error is from section above

    MsgBox ("val is " & found.Row)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub RemoveFooterRows(theFile)

    Dim found As Range

    Set found = Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find _
        ("Summary", Range("A1"), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False, , False)
    MsgBox ("val is " & found.Row)

End Sub
```

You need the "Set" keyword to assign the value.

Also not sure what you want " =isItRow =" to do but you should do it in two statements instead of trying to stack them like that.

Also aggregateRow isn't used and isn't assigned a type.

Comment: Also worth adding a check `If Not found Is nothing Then...` in case the value wasn't found.

Comment: Okay, that works, I didn't realize I had the double assignment. But, how do I get the row, when I add a .Row at the end I get the same error. How do I assign the row of found to a variable?

Comment: Add .row to what?  It's already in the MsgBox line and returns fine for me.

Comment: Good call on the checking for nothing Tim.

Comment: the Suggested if block is being skipped, implying the value wasn't found, but I know it is there in the first column. What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You use SET to find a cell and put it in an object.  But you can let SET out if you just waht the Row.  This is how I would write that test so far:

```
Dim Rw As Long

On Error Resume Next
Rw = Workbooks(theFile).Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Find _
    ("Summary", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart).Row

If Rw > 0 Then
    MsgBox "The row is " & Rw
Else
    MsgBox "Not found"
End If
```

Comment: What is the difference between your check and 'If Not found Is Nothing Then'

Comment: Using your code and commented out On Error Resume next, I get the same error. I used the find as I had written it. I know the value is in the column A, why is the error existing?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is there because if `.Find` doesn't find anything then `.Row` generates an error.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using Error Handling when a simple range object could be tested for Not Nothing. Plus `Find` can error out for other reasons that an unfound match, ie starting the seach in an invalid location, looking in an invalid range etc. Better to pinpoint these issues than skip over them

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub search()

    Sheets("MyShelf").Activate

    Dim dd() As String

    aa = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim dd(aa)

    i = 1

    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(aa, 1)).Select

    Set bb = Selection

    For Each cc In bb

        dd(i) = cc.Value

        i = i + 1

    Next

    Sheets(50).Activate

    ff = 0

        For i = 1 To aa - 1

        ee = Range("D:D").Find(What:=dd(i), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

        On Error Resume Next

        If Len(ee) > 1 Then

        ff = ff + 1

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox ff


End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks