# find dynamic variable code giving runtime error 91

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to bypass runtime error 91 (Object variable not Set) when ever I use the following code?

```
Dim findE As Range
findE = Sheets(1).Range("A:AAA").Find(What:="E", searchdirection:=xlLeft, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column
```

My findE is used to look for the text "E" and it may not appear all the time. Whenever it doesn't appear, it will produce the runtime error.

I tried using

```
Dim findE As Range
Set findE = Sheets(1).Range("A:AAA").Find(What:="E", searchdirection:=xlLeft, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns).Column

If not findE Is Nothing Then
'do something
end if
```

I still see the error. I did make some reference to this [VBA in find function runtime error 91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199951/vba-in-find-function-runtime-error-91) but still no help at all.Please advise me on this. Thank you.

Comment: After `Dim findE As Range`, insert `On Error Resume Next`. Not the finest but the fastest way :-) This will tell VBA to not show any error message in case the command in the next line fails. So you aren't really debugging, just disabling the error message.

Comment: @nhee is there any other options? As I am afraid there maybe underlining errors that will get masked off if i were to use that statement

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Keep in mind that this only disables errors in the following one line so you will still see errors from forthcoming lines after the find command. I found some hints googling 'excel vba find 91', can't spare you the research, sorry.

Comment: If `.Find` returns `Nothing`, how are you going to access its `Column` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

```
Dim FindE As Range
With Sheets(1).Range("A:AAA")
    Set FindE = .Find(What:="E", SearchDirection:=xlLeft, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    If Not FindE Is Nothing Then Set FindE = Columns(FindE.Column)
End With
```

Comment: thank you. Just to check with you, I need to use FindE in this format: cells(1,findE).copy by setting it as a column only, I won't be able to select other cells. In the meantime, I will try and find answer to it as well..

Comment: I was able to find a solution to it. Thanks for the earlier input! :)