# VBA Problem error 91 - Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

We use our excel reports in our virtual desktop. Now we are testing with our reports in Azure Virtual Desktop and there's a excel report coming out of a error:

```
Cells.Find(What:="zzz", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

I don't have much experience with this so i don't see what i have to change.
I need some help :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats the error? `VBA Problem error 91`, anything more to go off?

Comment: The yellow arrow puts out on the last line. It's about subtotals. This report is working in another virtual desktop. The error is only within Azure Virtual Desktop.

Comment: Double check its supported Google: KB257757 - first article.

Comment: Thank you. Some reports do work. Is that weird or can this be a problem for just a report.

Comment: Try and reproduce it on a few other machines and if its specific to Azure Virtual Desktops you may need to raise a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: @LucvanIersel Are you sure that the string is present in your search area (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879628/17172829)

Answer (score 0):

You should activate cell only after successful search.

```
Set result = Cells.Find(What:="zzz", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)
If result is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
Else
    result.Activate
End If
```